# Data, Time Validation using Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, validation, date

I want to write a shell script which will accept

1. date format
2. time format
3. date
4. time

from user and will validate the date and time.

For Example:

```
./test.sh mmddyyyy hhmmss 12122012 121212
```

should return the correct result.

Comment: well this is too broad. Please show a [mcve] and also check [ask].

Answer (score 1):

use this if you get 0 your date is valid

```
date "+%d/%m/%Y" -d "03/10/2016" > /dev/null  2>&1
 is_valid=$?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you are attempting by using either `if` or `case` statements along with `expr` operators to parse and validate the input to the script. The key is to parse and put the `date` and `time` components of the input into a format that can be interpreted by `date --date=""`. There are a number of approaches you can take. Below is a minimal example using your example input:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ "$#" -lt "4" ] && {
    printf "error: insufficient input.\n"
    printf "usage: %s datestr timestr date time\n" "${0//*\//}"
    printf "   eg: %s mmddyyyy hhmmss 01012011 122515\n" "${0//*\//}"
    exit 1
}

datestr=
timestr=

case "$1" in
    "mmddyyyy" )
        [ $(expr length "$3") -ne "8" ] && {
            printf "error: invalid date for format.\n"
            printf " '%s' != '%s'\n" "$1" "$3"
            exit 1
        }
        datestr="$(expr substr "$3" 1 2)"
        datestr="$datestr/$(expr substr "$3" 3 2)"
        datestr="$datestr/$(expr substr "$3" 5 4)"
        ;;
    * )    printf "error: invalid date format '%s'\n" "$1"
        ;;
esac

case "$2" in
    "hhmmss" )
        [ $(expr length "$4") -ne "6" ] && {
            printf "error: invalid time for format.\n"
            printf " '%s' != '%s'\n" "$2" "$4"
            exit 1
        }
        timestr="$(expr substr "$4" 1 2)"
        timestr="$timestr:$(expr substr "$4" 3 2)"
        timestr="$timestr:$(expr substr "$4" 5 2)"
        ;;
    * )    printf "error: invalid time format '%s'\n" "$2"
        ;;
esac

printf "%s\n" "$(date -d "$datestr $timestr")"

exit 0
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sh datetmstr.sh mmddyyyy hhmmss 12122012 121212
Wed Dec 12 12:12:12 CST 2012
```

You can build upon this approach to add additional date/time input formats. POSIX shell doesn't have the largest selection of string handling routines, but it has more than enough for this type of work.